# How to get the vue instance of a child element in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

If I have this vue component of

```
<Root>
    <Post>
        <AccountSelector ref="Account">
            <Account></Account>
            <Account></Account>
            <Account></Account>
        </AccountSelector>
    </Post>
</Root>
```

How can I access the Account element? If I do `this.$refs.Account` that just gives me the native DOM element. How can I get the vue instance of `Account`?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need that? what's the logic that you want to apply ?

Comment: Im trying to do a `$forceUpdate` to it so I need reference to it.

Comment: according to the official [doc](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Forcing-an-Update) *`If you find yourself needing to force an update in Vue, in 99.99% of cases, you’ve made a mistake somewhere`*, i think doing that is a bad practice

Comment: what about dependency injection ?

Comment: You are right. It was another issue. I fixed it.